# Too many indices for array numpy/python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indices

So I am trying to upload the file http://www.ice.csic.es/personal/aldos/Solar_Data_files/nudistr_b16_agss09.dat
into my code.

```
data= np.genfromtxt('nudistr_b16_agss09.csv',delimiter=',',skip_header=21)
t=data[:,1]  #temperature (10^6 K)
r=data[:,0]    #radius (units of one solar radius)
ne=data[:,2]   #Log base 10 of electron density (cm^{-3}/N_A,N_A is Avogadro number)
```

However I keep getting the error too many indices for array. I do not understand because I have used this format before and have not run into errors such as these before. What can I do to change it?

Comment: Try `print(data.shape)` on the second line to see if the dimensions of `data` match what you are expecting

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your data file uses newlines (not commas) as delimiters. Try removing the delimiter argument:

```
data= np.genfromtxt('nudistr_b16_agss09.dat',skip_header=21)
```

Comment: That seemed to resolve the issue, thank you so much!!

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept my answer if it solved the problem.